# multiple selectbox returns null if no selection in shortcode generator

Tags: javascript, select, conditional-statements, shortcode

I have a standard html dropdown for my shortcode generator form. If I have it as the basic single select, it doesn't add that attribute to my shortcode. If I change it to multiple, it adds: level="null" to my shortcode (where "level" is the name of the attribute. Here's the dropdown menu options:

```
<select name="level" id="tms-level" multiple>\
<option value=""></option>\
<option value="1">1</option>\
<option value="2">2</option>\
<option value="3">3</option>\
<option value="4">4</option>\
<option value="5">5</option>\
<option value="6">6</option>\
</select>
```

And here's the javascript being used at the end to generate the shortcode:

```
var table = form.find('table');
form.appendTo('body').hide();
form.find('#tms-submit').click(function(){
    var options = { 
        'logged'  : '',
    'level'   : '',
    };
var shortcode = '[tms';

for( var index in options) {
    var value = table.find('#tms-' + index).val();

    if ( value !== options[index] )
    shortcode += ' ' + index + '="' + value + '"';
}

    shortcode += '] Content here. [/tms]';

    tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, shortcode);

 tb_remove();
```

I guess maybe another conditional statement, like, if level=null don't include level in shortcode, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your condition for:

```
if ( value !== options[index] && value != null )
```

Note that I've used `!=` and not `!==` here to allow type coersion so that `null` and `undefined` values will not be added.